# Survcomp package, y z variables

Tags: survival-analysis

I am running the survcomp package and wonder about the y and z values. I have multiple clinical data:

```
> colnames(ClinicalDataHep)
 [1] "follow_upTime"                                              
 [2] "RecurrenceTime"                                             
 [3] "Age"                                                        
 [4] "OS"                                                         
 [5] "Survival_dead0_alive1"                                      
 [6] "Tumour_size"                                                
 [7] "HVB_preop"                                                  
 [8] "HCV_preop"                                                  
 [9] "HBD_preop"                                                  
[10] "Cirrhosis_preop"                                            
[11] "Status:_no_recurrence-0._recurrence-1_"                     
[12] "Surgery:_resection-1._tx-2;_rfa-3;_resection+rfa-4;tx+rfa-5"
[13] "new_time"                                                   
[14] "new_death"                                                  
[15] "death_event"
```

Is it corrent to use `Overall Survival` as the `y-variable` and `dead/alive` as the `z variable`?

```
cindexall.Hep.serum <- as.data.frame(t(apply(X=matrix_cpm, MARGIN=1, function(x, y, z) { 
  tt <- concordance.index(x=x, surv.time=y, surv.event=z, method="noether", na.rm=TRUE);  
  return(c("cindex"=tt$c.index, "cindex.se"=tt$se, "lower"=tt$lower, "upper"=tt$upper,"p.value"=tt$p.value)); }, 
  y=ClinicalData$OS,  z=ClinicalData$Survival_dead0_alive1)))
```